# Issues in setting Folder Attributes in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a little problem in setting the folder attributes in VB .NET.

What I need is to set the Hidden + System attributes for a folder.
I tried the methods 1 and 2 mentioned below. But only method 2 worked for me. Method 1 simply applies Hidden attribute only, not the Hidden + System.
Anyway, **I want to do my stuff only with method 1 since it is a pure .NET approach.** Please let me know what I'm doing wrong in Method 1.

**Method 1**

```
Dim fol As New DirectoryInfo("C\test\1")        
fol.Attributes = fol.Attributes & FileAttributes.System & FileAttributes.Hidden
```

**Method 2**

```
SetAttr("C\test\1", vbSystem + vbHidden)
```

Comment: use `Or` to combine them `fol.Attributes = fol.Attributes Or FileAttributes.System Or FileAttributes.Hidden`  use `And` to test for one flag or another

Comment: Thanks..., this worked almost perfect...,